# URL manipulation with JavaScript and regex

Tags: javascript

I am taking first steps with regular expressions. I am trying to increment the last digit in a url string but for some reason I cant figure out I increment other digits.

**Example**

string: `http://example.com/18-something-something/6`

should become: `http://example.com/18-something-something/7`

in practice: `http://example.com/19-something-something/7`

As you can see, `18` turned to `19` which is what im trying to avoid.

This is my JS:

```
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  url = window.location.href;

  var newrl = url.replace(/(\d+)+/g, function(match, number) {
    return parseInt(number) + 1;
  });

  var m = url.match(/\/([^\/]+)[\/]?$/);
  link = jQuery('a[class=nextpostslink]').attr('href');

  if (!isNumeric(m[1])) {
    jQuery('.post-content').find('img:first').wrap(jQuery("<div class='slideshow-wrapper'><a href=2>").attr("href", link));
    jQuery('.post-content').find('img:first').after('<div id="start-slideshow"><img src="chevron.png"></div>');
  } else {
    jQuery('.post-content').find('img:first').wrap(jQuery("<div class='slideshow-wrapper'><a href=" + newrl + ">").attr("href", link));
  }
});
```

Any idea what am I missing? thx

Comment: Is is always about the digit at the end of the url (noting followed by the digit)? Or is it about the last digit in the url and something can be followed by the digit?

Comment: there might be query string parameters. but the path itself (url without params) will always end up with a the digit i want to increment

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to have a global match (`g`), but removing that flag alone won't help.

If you want match with and without query parameter, then you need to make sure that it is either at the end of the string `$` or right before the query parameters `?`  so your RegExp has to look like this:

```js
var url = 'http://example.com/18-something-something/6?param=34';

var newrl = url.replace(/(\d+)($|\?)/, function(match, number, questionmark) {
  return String(++number) + questionmark;
});

console.log(newrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `/(\d+)$/` as a regex to increment only the last digit.

Answer (score -1):

I would not do this with regular expressions, truthfully.

I'd do something like:

```js
var url = "http://example.com/18-something-something/6";

function advanceUrl(url) {
  // Split the URL into chunks
  var chunks = url.split("/");

  // Get the last segment of the URL
  var lastPage = chunks.pop();

  // Increment it
  lastPage++;

  // And put it back
  chunks.push(lastPage);

  // Re-create the URL
  var newUrl = chunks.join("/");

  // Log it
  console.log(newUrl);

  // Return it.
  return newUrl;
}

advanceUrl(url);
```

Comment: in your answer result is `http://theviraldance.com/18-celebrities-who-look-amazingly-alike/6/1`